# python Popen does not capture program's stdout. Unsure why

Tags: python, popen

I have three programs.  The first is one just to test reading from `subprocess.Popen`.  The second is a program that has stdout and stdin using `cout`/`cin` in c++.  The third is the exact same application, except it uses `printf` and `fgets`.

```
import subprocess
import shlex
import os


def main():
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        shlex.split('/home/art/dlm/test1'),
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE
    )
    data = b''
    old_len = 0
    while True:
        print('Progress 1')
        data += proc.stdout.read(1)
        print('Progress 2')
        if old_len == len(data):
            break
        old_len = len(data)
        print(data)
    print('Progress 3')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Program #2.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char _input[100];
    cout << "Line 1 test" << endl;
    cout << "Line 1 test" << endl;
    cout << "Line 3 test" << endl;
    cout << "Thoughts? ";
    cin >> _input;
    cout << _input << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

The output from c++ program #2 is read byte for byte and printed to screen, exactly how I'd expect.  Below is Program #3.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char _input[100];
    /*cout << "Line 1 test" << endl;
    cout << "Line 2 test" << endl;
    cout << "Line 3 test" << endl;
    cout << "Thoughts? ";*/
    printf("Line 1 test\n");
    printf("Line 2 test\n");
    printf("Line 3 input: ");
    fgets(_input, sizeof(_input), stdin);
    printf("Line 4 test: %s\n", _input);
    //cin >> _input;
    //cout << _input << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

This output does NOT get seen by the `Popen` pipe.  In fact, if I redirect it to a file, the file captures 0 bytes.

This is a test I'm doing because I have an application at work that is written the same way as Program #3 using `printf` and `fgets` and I'm trying to write a python3 script to communicate with it.  I do NOT know some of the prompts beforehand, so it's got to be handled with 2-way communication.

How can I read from Program #3 using `Popen`'s stdout?  Bonus points:  Why do Programs #2 and #3 function so differently in this manner?

Comment: Your usage of `shlex.split()` looks incorrect. It doesn't do anything on a single token, and the parts which need splitting are outside the parentheses. The correct end result should apparently be `['/home/art/dlm/test1', 'bin/dlm', '-i']`.

Comment: You might want to mention what C library and OS you're using. This may be a C/C++ issue, rather than a Python issue. Python can't do much if your program isn't using standard output for `printf`.

Comment: @tripleee, you are correct!  Sorry, I must have copy/pasted the code while I was in the middle of swapping to the non-shlex syntax.  I've edited the code and it is now correct.

Comment: @Blckknght It was compiled with `g++ -o test test.cpp` as the command line and ALL of the source code is included above.  There is nothing extra beyond that.  The OS is CentOS 7 with latest updates from `yum`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the buffer is not flushed after the `printf()` statements, a workaround I've found is to use `stdbuf -o0`, forcing the application in question to buffer its output (or in this case, disable buffering).  This fixes all of the associated woes and handles it just fine for my purposes.  Thank you to the responders!